# ExoPlayer: play a video with chuncks

Tags: java, android, websocket, exoplayer

Through WebSocket, I'm getting chunks of a video file that I want it to play immediately in ExoPlayer. In fact, I'm trying to implement video file streaming which works very well on the web page with MediaSource and appendBuffer which update the player with a new chunk. So I want something similar to that.

Here is where I'm receiving chunks

```
@Override
public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
    // here is chunk
    // bytes.hex()
    // I want to update exoplayer or to start exoplayer in case it is the first chunk
}
```

I've been looking for how to do it but I didn't find a solution. So I really need help